# How to change the checkbox background using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox, background-color

I am having three check boxes on my form. I would like to change the background color of the check boxes when checked. Is it possible to write a single script for all the check boxes on my form?

Answer (score 5):

Changing background colour of checkboxes isn't consistent across browsers.

Take a look at [this link](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/form_controls/checkboxes/) for an indication of how they'll look.

If you want to change the background colour and have it work consistently, you may well be better off looking at a JavaScript forms extension.

This link provides a few: [25+ jQuery Plugins that enhance and beautify HTML form elements](http://www.queness.com/post/204/25-jquery-plugins-that-enhance-and-beautify-html-form-elements) and Google will provide many more.

---

**EDIT:** If you *do* want to work around it using jQuery, you can use [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) and [`unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) to add a coloured `span` around the checkbox. This won't change the background of the checkbox itself, but it will provide some visual feedback in a reliable way.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    $(this).unwrap().filter(":checked").wrap("<span class='selected'>");
});
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/B2n2J/)

Comment: Hi but i am using asp controls how can i use this

Comment: ASP.NET CheckBoxes render as `input` elements with a type of `checkbox`.

Comment: @user552236: _"did not work for me"_ isn't really enough information for anyone to help you...

Comment: @Town let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1006/discussion-between-user552236-and-town)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET markup:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkBox" />
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('#checkBox') // select by id
    .css('backgroundColor', value); // set value
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using CSS/Javascript to change the background of the checkbox, which will have issues cross-browser (as @Town has pointed out) I would recommend using the ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit's "Toggle Button" control. Then use an image of a checked checkbox (print screen or designed if you wish), and the same image unchecked.

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/ToggleButton/ToggleButton.aspx

This control uses the CheckBox control so you would have all the usual functionalities of an ASP.NET CheckBox too

Answer (score -1):

This is exactly the kind of thing [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is designed to do.